# How do i add an image using a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, image, bookmarklet

I am making bookmarklets for fun and I want to add a picture (if possible a gif) to the middle of the screen I have tried many ways and none have worked.

Here is the bookmarklet am working on and I am trying to make it so when ran a picture of Rick Astley will show up

```
javascript:var audio = new Audio('https://media1.vocaroo.com/mp3/12OdDSvf3CkE');  audio.play();
```

I have tried to use

```
javascript:var img = document.createElement('img');img.src = 'https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/156-1560736_smiley-transparent-smiley-face-clipart.png';// TODO: set position and whatnotbody.appendChild(img);
```

But that just opens the link and not the image

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = 'https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/156-1560736_smiley-transparent-smiley-face-clipart.png';
document.getElementById('imgdiv').appendChild(img);
```

```html
<div id="imgdiv">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried using that in a bookmarklet and it wouldn't work I think it is because of the div element which I don't know how you would implement that using java.